# Typescript not checking function argument types declared by interfaces

Tags: typescript

I was expecting TWO errors when compiling the code below, but typescript compiles it without any errors.

```
interface IFoo{
    Bar(callback: (arg:string) => void):void;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    public Bar(callback: () => void):void{
        callback();
    }
}

var foo: IFoo;
foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar(() => {
    console.log("Hi");
})
```

Expected Error 1:  IFoo.Bar requires a function argument which itself takes a string argument.  However, when Foo implements IFoo, Foo.Bar is declared to take a function argument with NO arguments.  I would expect this to be a type error.

Expected Error 2:  foo is of type IFoo.  foo.Bar is called with a function argument that takes no arguments, contrary to the definition of Bar in IFoo.  I would expect this to be a type error.

So both when declaring a concrete implementation of an interface method, and also when calling the interface method, it seems that the type of the function signature is not being enforced.

Clearly I am misunderstanding how typescript handles type checking of function arguments declared by an interface.  Can someone explain why this compiles without error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is answered in the [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters). Here is the text of that answer:

This is the expected and desired behavior.
First, refer to the "substitutability" primer at the top of the FAQ -- `handler` is a valid argument for `callback` because it can safely ignored extra parameters.

Second, let's consider another case:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3];
items.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
```

This is isomorphic to the example that "wanted" an error.
At runtime, `forEach` invokes the given callback with three arguments (value, index, array), but most of the time the callback only uses one or two of the arguments.
This is a very common JavaScript pattern and it would be burdensome to have to explicitly declare unused parameters.

Comment: That certainly explains the behavior.  Thanks.  It is still surprising to me that this was designed like this.  Since Typescript allows us to specifically declare optional arguments on a function, it seems reasonable to expect that if a function is declared with arguments that are not declared optional, that they are indeed not optional.  I would argue that for the examples cited above from the FAQ (and for both of the issues in the code I posted above), that it really should only compile if the argument were specified as optional.

Comment: Call signatures are always interpreted from the *calling* side, where optionality means "It might be missing", not "You might not look at it". A callback reading `(x?: string) => void` means "I might invoke you with one string argument, or I might invoke you with zero arguments"

Comment: Unfortunately, though, everyone misinterpreted this aspect of call signatures and wrote definition files with optional parameters in a bunch of callback signatures (as though it's up to the library author to decide WHICH PARAMETERS YOU MUST LOOK AT rather than letting you make that determination), so the type system ignore optionality in this specific case.

Comment: I would add that this have nothing to do with callback and interface. The way 
I see it is if you're calling a function with more arguments than expected, obviously this wouldn't cause any bug. When you apply this to callbacks it gets a little bit counter intuitive because of this caller vs called reversal.