# Interface signature not matching

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out why I'm getting an error for this:

```
export interface IGrid {
    (gridCell: GridCell): boolean
}
```

In my class I have

```
foo(gridCell: GridCell): boolean {
    return true;
}
```

Error:

> Class 'X' incorrectly implements interface 'IGrid'.   Type 'X'
>   provides no match for the signature '(gridCell: GridCell): boolean'

**Update:**

I've added a parameter to the interface's gridFormat signature.

```
export interface IGrid {
    gridFormat(gridCell: GridCell, x: number): boolean
}
```

Class:

```
gridFormat(gridCell: GridCell): boolean {
    return true;
}
```

Problem now is there is no error, the class doesn't implement the function with the `x: number` paramter. How can I get the interface to require the function properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IGrid` interface is a [function interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types), meaning the interface describes a function. You can implement it like this:

```
let yourFunc: IGrid = (gridCell: GridCell): boolean => {
    return true;
};
```

If you want to implement it in a class your interface should probably declare a [class type interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types) with function members:

```
export interface IGrid {
    foo(gridCell: GridCell): boolean
}

class Grid implements IGrid {
    foo(gridCell: GridCell): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Re: Why there is no error when the implementation is missing a parameter defined in interface:**

This is by design. See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6298) and the [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: Okay, that works but I still can't get my interface working how I want it to. I've updated the question. Signatures do not match yet there are no errors.

Comment: @el_pup_le That is actually by design. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541247/typescript-not-checking-function-argument-types-declared-by-interfaces) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: thanks, that's quite frustrating. I see you're a C# guy, do you know if C# is designed like this?

Comment: @el_pup_le No. C# supports method overloads, so something like this will throw an error in C#. JavaScript (which TypeScript compiles to) does not have method overloading.

Comment: Is it possible to force a class to have a function that fully match's an interface's function signature? No optional parameters allowed.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with TypeScript. In practice, you shouldn't have a problem with this. It is the implementation that is choosing to ignore the parameter.