# Typescript interface property as typed function arguments not being enforced

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface Field {
  type: string;
  value: (argument1: string, argument2: string) => string;
}

const field: Field = {
  type: 'text',
  value: () => 'Hello'
};
```

Why isn't typescript enforcing the `argument1` and `argument2`? This code compiles with no problems, I want typescript to make sure that the function is exactly as I typed it in the interface definition.

Comment: I found a similar question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541247/typescript-not-checking-function-argument-types-declared-by-interfaces TS doesn't enforce it because the arguments are safely ignored.

Comment: @senta thanks for the link! what do you mean with 'safely ignored'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why isn't typescript enforcing the argument1 and argument2?

The purpose of the type is to enforce that when the function is called those parameters must be passed in. The type does not mean that the function has to do anything with those arguments though. It would be legal to write a function like the following, which lists the arguments and then does nothing with them:

```
value: (argument1: string, argument2: string) => 'Hello'
```

That's extra typing for no benefit though, since javascript functions can take any number of parameters regardless of which ones are listed. So typescript also lets you not bother listing them, while still being compatible with the type. If you list an argument with a type that doesn't match it will tell you, but omitting is not a problem.

Typescript was deliberately designed this way. See this section of the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions

> You may be wondering why we allow ‘discarding’ parameters like in the example y = x. The reason for this assignment to be allowed is that ignoring extra function parameters is actually quite common in JavaScript. For example, Array#forEach provides three parameters to the callback function: the array element, its index, and the containing array. Nevertheless, it’s very useful to provide a callback that only uses the first parameter:
>
> ```
> let items = [1, 2, 3];
>
> // Don't force these extra parameters
> items.forEach((item, index, array) => console.log(item));
>
> // Should be OK!
> items.forEach(item => console.log(item));
> ```